# Joshua Bloch's Builder pattern and PMD warnings

Tags: java, pmd, builder-pattern

I have written a class using Joshua Bloch's Builder pattern, which is similar to this Pizza example:

```
public class Pizza {
  private int size;
  private boolean cheese;
  private boolean pepperoni;
  private boolean bacon;

  public static class Builder {
    //required
    private final int size;

    //optional
    private boolean cheese = false;
    private boolean pepperoni = false;
    private boolean bacon = false;

    public Builder(int size) {
      this.size = size;
    }

    public Builder cheese(boolean value) {
      cheese = value;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder pepperoni(boolean value) {
      pepperoni = value;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder bacon(boolean value) {
      bacon = value;
      return this;
    }

    public Pizza build() {
      return new Pizza(this);
    }
  }

  private Pizza(Builder builder) {
    size = builder.size;
    cheese = builder.cheese;
    pepperoni = builder.pepperoni;
    bacon = builder.bacon;
  }
}
```

but PMD reported 2 warnings:

1. (Pointing to method Builder.build())
   Avoid instantiation through private constructors from outside of
   the constructor's class.
   Instantiation by way of private
   constructors from outside of the
   constructor's class often causes the
   generation of an accessor. A factory
   method, or non-privitization of the
   constructor can eliminate this
   situation. The generated class file
   is actually an interface.  It gives
   the accessing class the ability to
   invoke a new hidden package scope
   constructor that takes the interface
   as a supplementary parameter.  This
   turns a private constructor
   effectively into one with package
   scope, and is challenging to
   discern.
2. Class cannot be instantiated and
   does not provide any static methods
   or fields. A class that has private
   constructors and does not have any
   static methods or fields cannot be
   used.

Should I just ignore these warnings?

Another question: the private fields in class `Pizza` and `Builder` are duplicate. This will be annoying when the number of private fields getting bigger. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: for 1. you could maybe define your Pizza constructor as package-protected. This should also solve 2.

Comment: The pattern is a good one; PMD is just being dumb.  I'd ignore it, personally.

Comment: just a side note: I've been using a tiny framework called [Make-It-Easy](http://code.google.com/p/make-it-easy/) for a while, which helps to build this *builders* and the code is quite readable. I use it mostly for my unit tests, but it could be definitely used for production code.

Comment: I would ignore the first PMD warning. The second one, though, is justified. Your Pizza class, as it is in your question, is unusable since it doesn't have any method. Throw in some getters, and PMD won't complain anymore (hopefully).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About how to remove duplication.

I'll get more downvotes :) But maybe something like this?

```
class Pizza {
private int size;
private boolean cheese;
private boolean pepperoni;
private boolean bacon;

public static class Builder {
    private Pizza pizza = new Pizza();

    public Builder(int size) {
        pizza.size = size;
    }

    public Builder cheese(boolean value) {
        pizza.cheese = value;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder pepperoni(boolean value) {
        pizza.pepperoni = value;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder bacon(boolean value) {
        pizza.bacon = value;
        return this;
    }

    public Pizza build() {
        return pizza;
    }
}

private Pizza() {
}
}
```

Comment: I don't like this. You can change fields on your Pizza via the Builder that created it AFTER calling build(). One of the best uses for the builder pattern is to ease the creation of immutable classes.

Comment: Sorry, but with this style you still also get: 1) "Avoid instantiation through private constructors from outside of the constructor's class." and 2) "Class cannot be instantiated and does not provide any static methods or fields", so the problems are not solved.

Answer (score 1):

> the private fields in class Pizza and
>   Builder  are duplicate. This will be
>   annoying when the number of private
>   fields getting bigger. Is there any
>   way to avoid it?

I personally get around this by using a third private static value object class which contains all the fields and use it both in the builder and main class (field access is handled by delegation). Sure, this might end up inflating the line count/class count but is invaluable in case your builders end up being complicated with a large number of fields and checks.

Also, it won't hurt to actually provide a static method on the Pizza class which builds a Pizza object with the mandatory fields. Unless of course you are not sure what the mandatory fields are or are afraid that the mandatory fields may change during the course of your class evolution. Point being, as long as you can justify your actions after a lot of thought (like Joshua Bloch puts it), you can safely ignore those warnings knowing that you know what you are doing. :-)

A throwaway snippet:

```
public class Pizza {

    private final PizzaVO vo;

    private static class PizzaVO {

        int size;

        boolean cheese;

        boolean pepperoni;

        boolean bacon;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private final PizzaVO vo = new PizzaVO();

        public Builder(int size) {
            vo.size = size;
        }

        public Builder cheese(boolean value) {
            vo.cheese = value;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder pepperoni(boolean value) {
            vo.pepperoni = value;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder bacon(boolean value) {
            vo.bacon = value;
            return this;
        }

        public Pizza build() {
            return new Pizza(vo);
        }
    }

    private Pizza(PizzaVO vo) {
        this.vo = vo;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return vo.size;
    }

    // other getter setter methods as per your taste

}
```

Comment: It´s not worth using this style. The problems are not solved.

Comment: hi aloplop85, can you clarify which problems are not solved, and why?

Comment: @sudocoder at minimum the PMD error "Avoid instantiation through private constructors from outside of the constructor's class." would still be present